# ¿Cómo aplicar estilo CSS a GUI usando QtDesigner?

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Quiero agregarles estilos CSS a las ventanas y botones de mi proyecto realizado en Python y PyQt, a través de Qt Design. ¿Dónde y cómo agrego el código CSS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para establecer Qt Style Sheets a traves de Qt Designer debes hacer click derecho sobre el widget, aparecera un menu, en este debes seleccionar la opción `Change styleSheet`, como muestro en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer lo anterior aparece una venta de dialogo y en ella puedes colocar el qss, este tiene:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe decir Qt Style Sheets no es css, soportar caracteristicas similares a css2 (propiedades de css3 no son soportadas), en los siguientes enlaces puedes tener mayor informacion de las reglas:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-stylesheet.html

Una recomendacion es no añadir el qss directamente en la GUI, sino crear un .qss donde definamos las reglas, la importamos y la establecemos por codigo:

```
stream = QtCore.QFile("/path/of/your.qss")
stream.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
qApp.setStyleSheet(QtCore.QTextStream(stream).readAll())
```